# Understanding SEM output

Tags: chi-squared-test, structural-equation-modeling

I'm trying to understand the result of the summary of the `sem()` function of the same package. The model is made using the data of a study conducted by Will Vincent.

[image: path diagram]

Here is the result:

[image: summary(semmodel)]

Now, I can use the AIC and BIC  to compare one model with another, the parameters gam22, la11, lam22 are not significant and the normalized residuals are around zero. R-squares inform me the variance of each endogenous variable that's predictable from the independent variables.

My questions are:

1. What can I say about the model chi-square? If I'm right,. it's obtained comparing the model with an over-identified model that represents perfectly my data, and in that case, non-significance means that 2 models are similar. Am I right?
2. What is the meaning of iteration? Why in the other example that I found it's always different from zero and not in this one?

Answer (score 2):

The chi-square test is essentially a likelihood ratio test comparing your model to a fully saturated model. As with any likelihood ratio test of nested models, it tests whether relaxing constraints (i.e., estimating more parameters) significantly improves model fit, with the null hypothesis that estimating more parameters does not improve model fit. In SEM, the null hypothesis is that, as you said, your constrained model fits as well as a fully saturated (i.e., with constraints maximially relaxed) model. You reject the null hypothesis when your model does not fit as well as a saturated model, i.e., that you have over-constrained your model. Constraints usually take the form of implicitly setting the path from one variable to another to be equal to 0; for example, you implicitly constrained the coefficient on the direct effect of Religiosity on Alcohol-Related Aggression to be 0.

Iterations happen when you need to use an iterative procedure for obtaining maximum likelihood estimates, which, in the case of linear SEM, would only occur when latent variables are present, and it doesn't look like you have any. The maximum likelihood estimates for linear models can be estimated using an analytical formula rather than iterating through various parameter guesses to maximize the likelihood. This may be why there are no iterations.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Well, you have not found that the models are significantly different.
2. We don't know about the other example. This took zero iterations because the starting values were the best estimates, so the model did not need to iterate.